# Nirodhah and Asamsayam mahābhāo meanings in Dhyānayogo shl. 35

Tags: mahabharata, bhagavad-gita, adi-shankaracharya, ramanujacharya, yoga-sutras

Ch. Dhyānayogo , translated with "Il vero Yoga", = The True Yoga. Chapter number 6 for my edition.

श्रीभगवानुवाच |
असंशयं महाबाहो मनो दुर्निग्रहं चलम् |
अभ्यासेन तु कौन्तेय वैराग्येण च गृह्यते || 35||

Romanized [IAST]

śhrī bhagavān uvācha

asanśhayaṁ mahā-bāho| mano durnigrahaṁ chalam|
abhyāsena tu kaunteya| vairāgyeṇa cha gṛihyate||

In my edition [Bhagavad Gita by Icilio Vecchiotti italian Sanskrit student with a translated Preface and Intro by S. Radhakrishnan; the ed. used Ramanuja, Shankaracharya comments among others. Edited by Ubaldini Editors, Rome, Italy, first edition 1964],

√ related to this verse above the translator relies on comparison with Yog Suutra I, 12:

" abhyāsavairāghyābhyām tan nirodhah"

And it translates this with "arresting- stopping the [psyche] functions it is [conveyed performed] through exercising detachement".

So non-attachment exercised constantly, do practically helps the *manas* to let detachment arrive.

Author mention also the need for *tapasya* = austhere devotion.

---

1. How is detachement concept associated in the shloka with the compounded whole verse?
2. Nirodhah word exact meaning and Asamsayam mahābhāo
   meanings

Thank you

---

To Stack Exchange: The expected answers are linked to the Sanskrit terms of the shlok. That's it.

Comment: I advise to ask 1 question at a time as per the rules.

Comment: Not constructive and unfriendly discussions have been purged. Avoid getting engaged in rude arguments. Just flag the problematic one and move on.

Comment: @Pandya ok, I want to flag your friend Ram. The reasons you can find in the thread who were here, you deleted these but I screenshotted all.

Comment: @Pandya, Vishwad Parishad, Rss, Ramakrishna, ISKON, no one of them discouraged me to learn and chant mantras from Vedas as your friend Ram say. Are 7 years that I am into that. I also like your granthalaya Public channell. Nice books. Something in devanagari still not easy but I m learning.

Comment: @hindustudent do not focus on person, focus on content. Also note that this site don't endorse any political issues